# SQL Server Locking hint in insert Statement does not Grant the Specified Lock

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, locking

I am trying to optimize my query execution time Using Lowest Lock level(Rowlock) but it Does not take effect "higher Locks Level Are Granted (IX)" when tracing in SQL profiler ,

My scenario:

- assuming I have two tables `dbo.Students` and `dbo.University`
- `dbo.Students` has a foreign key column to the `University` table

Query

```
INSERT INTO  dbo.Students WITH (ROWLOCK) (UniversityId, StudentName)
```

When Trace Locks in sql profile

- `Student` table granted IX (intent Exclusive)
- `University` table granted sch_s (schema stabilization)

and there many Page and Key locks granted and released before releasing these two locks.

Can anyone help me grant row locks only in the students table?

Comment: You'll be getting locks on referenced table unless you drop the FK. How server should check data integrity without doing this check (i.e. looking for corresponding row in referenced table)? Are you sure there is something to optimize here? May be you should look into number of indices, into triggers and the length of the whole transaction if this is not the only operation in it?

Comment: i am not sure but i thought i can lower down the Lock level from IX (intent exclusive) on the whole table To RowX (Exclusive on row only) i tried removing the identity from the primary key column but it still granted lock on the whole table @IvanStarostin

Comment: Those locks are absolutely correct - they say to other transactions that they can't exclusively lock whole table or page (where the locked row lays) because a part of it is already locked right now. IX locks speed up checks for existence of such lower-level locks. Otherwise  server would have to check each row consequentially. And all you say still looks like a premature optimization. If your select stays locked for some reason - optimize your select. This is an atomic insert (if there are no triggers or something). Are you sure you have any reason for "optimizing" it?

Comment: in my case i am concerned with inserting big number of records to table concurrently , which perform slow when i  run a performance test , so i think in reducing lock overhead as much as possible ,so  other sessions's transactions can insert to the same table concurrently @Ivan Starostin

Comment: Insert by smaller parts. Or you are inserting from client-side row by row? Are your PKs of int or guid type?

Comment: yes my PKs are int @Iivan-starostin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description of behavior**

Very likely, there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint between these two tables defined on `dbo.Students` table thus:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Students
...
[ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name]
FOREIGN KEY (UniversityId)
REFERENCES dbo.University (UniversityId)
```

Very likely, this constraint is enabled (see `sys.foreign_keys.is_disabled`) and SQL Server is "*forced*" to check this integrity constraint:
when somebody insert a row into dbo.Students with not null `@UniversityId` it checks if that `uid` already exist in `dbo.University.UniversityId` column.
This means that SQL Server have to lock somehow some keys/records from unique index associated with `dbo.University.UniversityId` column (a foreign key must reference one or more columns which are the key of an unique index).
Note: As far as I remember a comment coming from a former member of SQL Server Dev Team, SQL Server uses Serializable isolation level for such checks (I don't have any ref. for this info).

**Question**

> Can anyone help me grant row locks only in the students table?

**"Solution" (not)**

Basically you want to avoid locking on dbo.University table.
There is one solution (untested): droping foreign key constraint but it's NOT RECOMMENDED.

Comment: thanks @Bogdan Sahlean this briefly demonstrate locking on the referenced table but what about locking on the main table (can be lowered t row lock)

Comment: @MosabMelhim: The first check I would do is to see if `sys.indexes.allow_row_locks` is 1 or 0.